# Displaying pdf files in android app using qml - building poppler on windows for android

Tags: android, qt, cmake, windows-10, qml

I'm working on an app for android which has to display pdf files without using external viewers. For various reasons, the app is developed using qml/qt on windows 10 with the qt creator.

I found two possible solutions for my problem:

1. QtPDF would be perfect. Sadly, it isn't supported for android which has been confirmed by Qt's support team. The priority for adding android is quite low so no hoping that it will be usable in the near future (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83459))
2. Poppler (especially the poppler-qml-plugin found [here](https://github.com/dept2/Poppler-QML-plugin)). Seems to do what is needed only I have had no success in building it. I tried finding a cross-compiling solution as I suppose I will need to use the android compiler...

I have little experience in using qt creator and especially in developing on this setup for android. Would be great if anyone has already worked with a configuration like that and could help me!

My Setup:
Windows 10
Qt 5.15.2
Qt Creator 4.14.0
Android NDK 21.3.6528147

Target ABIs are
x86 (AVD)
armeabi-v7a
arm64-v8a

#### **EDIT**

I decided to follow the "poppler approach".

What I did so far:
I got the poppler source code and attempted a first build. CMake couldn't find Freetype, so I got it's source, build it and fed it to CMake. Then I had to do the same for JPEG (I assume this is openjpeg2), ZLIB, PNG and TIFF. zlib, png and tiff are accepted, though CMake throws an error regarding JPEG: "ooops"

precisely: "CMake Error at [...]/3rdParty/openjpeg/build-openjpeg-2.4.0-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Release/OpenJPEGConfig.cmake:41 (message): ooops Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:251 (find_package)"

and additionally, Cairo and Boost could not be found. So my question at this point is: am I doing this right? Is it the correct approach to find out one by one what other libs I have to build? Or am I missing something? Because I got to admit, I'm quite lost and don't really know what I'm doing...

Comment: What were problems to build `poppler`? And why are you restricted in some external applications? Actually it would be nice solution. Also I would try to use `WebView` with enabled plugins ...

Comment: @folibis The biggest problem building poppler is finding all the 3rdparty libs it depends on. So far, I'm stuck trying to build openjpeg which depends on openpng which should be built but just throws an error that i can't get around yet ([...]\3rdParty\openjpeg\openjpeg-2.4.0\thirdparty\libpng\pngrutil.c:3976: error: undefined reference to 'png_init_filter_functions_neon').

Comment: @folibis I tried to use WebView as you suggested. It seems the option to enable plugins is not available from the qml-side - do you know how to enable them? Because without, the WebView element is just empty